# Why do I get "undefined method 'paginate'" error in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate, nomethoderror

I get this error when using will_paginate on production server:

```
I, [2013-10-24T20:17:40.386696 #18564]  INFO -- : Started GET "/meals" for 190.273.432.55 at 2013-10-24 20:17:40 +0000
I, [2013-10-24T20:17:40.388972 #18564]  INFO -- : Processing by MealsController#index as HTML
I, [2013-10-24T20:17:40.395022 #18564]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
F, [2013-10-24T20:17:40.396720 #18564] FATAL -- :
NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Meal:0x00000005080598>):
  app/controllers/meals_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

This is how I use it in the controller:

```
@meals = current_user.meals.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
```

My view is:

```
<%= will_paginate @meals %>
```

I already tried the solution suggested in "[will_paginate error in production NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263225/will-paginate-error-in-production-nomethoderror-undefined-method-page-for)" and [the same question on GitHub](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/308) but it didn't work. I also checked that server and local have the same Ruby installation.

This works in development. The server setup is: 
Ubuntu 12.10, Nginx, Unicorn, Capistrano, Ruby 2.0.0p247, Rails 4.0.0. Any suggestions?

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "figaro"
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
```

Deploy.rb is:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"

server "xxxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "xxxx"
set :user, "xxxx"
set :port, xxxx
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:xxxx/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

**UPDATE:** I reinstalled the server, now it works. Don't know why...

Comment: Can you give some more info? What version of Rails? Can you post the output of the web server console, not just the error but some of what comes before it?

Comment: Also, can you check your Gemfile to ensure that the will_paginate gem is not in a subsection for development and isn't getting called for production. Also check this out: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/308

Comment: Have you set the params[:page] variable?

Comment: where should I set the params[:page] variable? In my view I use: `<%= will_paginate @meals %>`

Comment: @Beartech Added more information; I checked the github issue but didn't work...

Comment: Why don't you try using the paginate method on a "naked" query? I think it's because you're using it on an association that it's not being called. I read another question with exactly the same problem, and I've also had the issue myself before too. You might want to try this query: `@meals = Meal.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)`

Comment: This syntax might not be entirely correct - so if it throws an SQL error, we can work to fix it

Comment: @RichPeck I tried but still get the same error `undefined method paginate for Relation...`. I even tried the simple query `@meals = Meal.paginate(:page => params[:page])` but it's the same error. The fact that it works on my local machine makes me think, that the error has something to do with my server setup...

Comment: It could be! Is your database localhost or in Amazon's cloud or something?

Comment: Currently it's localhost, Postgres. (Local I use Sqlite)

Comment: Can you go to the Rails console on the production server and try calling `Gem.loaded_specs.keys` to see everything that loaded?

Comment: I reinstalled the server, now it's working - don't know why..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reinstalled the server, now it works. Don't know why...

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you mean by "reinstalled the server"?

Comment: I just reseted the VPS.

Comment: Well, here's one more up vote to a vague "answer" - just because - lol

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue while working on a new rails 5 app.

I tried restarting the server but without success.  What fixed it was restarting the spring server (after stopping other rails processes):

```
$ spring stop
```

then I restarted the rails server and everything worked again!

Comment: Can't believe that was the solution for me too, same problem. This is at least the 3rd time spring has caused a baffling malfunction in development.  I just took it out of my gemfile.

Comment: This also fixed my problem (where restarting server did not).

Answer (score 2):

I would try with different versions of gem, if that does not work try to add

```
require 'will_paginate'
```

in meals_controller.rb

also you can try do a fresh install of all of your gems.

```
bundle clean --force
bundle install
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

restarting the web server worked for me!

```
First quit the web server by typing  "Control c" on your terminal and then

$ rails server
```

after that go to your http://localhost:3000 on your web browser, and you should be fine now!