# Why is "rails runner -e production" not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, rvm-capistrano

To solve my problem, which is discussed in "[will_paginate error in production undefined method 'paginate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577344/will-paginate-error-in-production-undefined-method-paginate)", I tried running:

```
script/rails runner -e production
```

and:

```
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production
```

on the server like suggested in this github issue: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/308#issuecomment-17167158

But I get the following error:

```
bundler: command not found: script/rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Bundle install doesn't help. Any suggestions?

I'm using: Ruby 2.0.0p247, Rails 4.0.0, Ubuntu 12.10 LTS, Unicorn, Capistrano

Comment: What about `bundle exec rails runner -e production`?

Comment: I already tried that...

Comment: Your first suggestion is working; I didn't see that you removed "script/". Do you want to post the answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: 'script/rails' doesn't exist in rails 4 version try without 'script/'

Comment: @Monk_Code great to hear! Sure, will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

`bundle exec rails runner -e production`.

Answer (score 5):

[Use bin/rails runner for rails4 (when the bin/rails file exists)](https://github.com/javan/whenever/pull/350)