# script/runner:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- commands/runner (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, systemd

I'm trying to start a class method inside my Rails model with cron and systemd.

Unfortunatelly there seems to be somekind of path-problem when cron tries to activate the proper Rails method.

Below is my runner-script and the line causing the problem is the 3rd:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/runner'
```

Complete error message after this is shown below:

```
Apr 01 09:00:01 myapp systemd[1]: Started Myapp ModelA method b.
Apr 01 09:00:02 myapp runner[25783]: /srv/myapp/current/script/runner:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- commands/runner (LoadError)
Apr 01 09:00:02 myapp runner[25783]: from /srv/myapp/current/script/runner:3:in `<main>'
```

Or maybe it's because Rails is playing 1st of april's fool's joke on me?

Comment: I found partly similar problem: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1749534 but I don't use rvm there so I guess it isn't much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that myapp was recently updated from Rails 2.3 to Rails 4.1 and, as a legacy, `/script` folder was still used for starting runner.

Proper way to start runner in Rails 4 would be to use bin/rails script like this:

```
bin/rails runner "Model.method"
```

Another problem I had was that I had `bin/*` specified in my `.gitignore` file so `bin/rails` script wasn't even in the server.

I got help from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684019/1677069) and from [RailsGuides page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).